# How to match a decimal letter and blank in vim?

Tags: regex, vim

I need to change

```
1  A
2  B
3  C
4  D
```

to

```
A
B
C
D
```

which means the decimal letter at the begining of every line and the following one or more blank should be deleted .

I'm only familiar with Reqex in Perl, so I try to use :%s/^\d\s+// to solve my problem, but it does not work. so does anyone of you can tell me how to get the work done using vim ?

thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Vim needs a backslash for +, so try

`:%s/^\d\s\+//`

Comment: Brian, hope you don't mind, I added the ":%" to ensure it's an ex command and works across all lines, not just the current one.

Comment: Not at all. I figured the OP knew this, so my point was just that Vim is funny when it comes to +, but it is good to have the complete command for reference. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

One way is to use the global command with the search-and-replace command:

```
:g/^[0-9]  */s//
```

It searches for the sequence:

- start of line `^`
- a digit `[0-9]`
- a space `<space>`
- zero or more spaces `<space>*`

and then substitutes it for nothing `(s//)`.

While you can do a similar thing with just the search-and-replace command on its own, it's useful to learn the global command since you can do all sorts of wonderful things with the lines selected (not just search and replace).

Comment: +1,this global search feature is very interesting, ":s" has done everything I needed so I never looked further into the search features

Comment: @Fire Crow: If i were using global feature, I'd write `:%g/^\d/norm ^dW`

Comment: The :s command is really just a shorthand way of doing :g with a substitute command (and across the whole file). Its power lies in the fact that it's not limited to substitution - you can use it to execute any colon command on the lines/patterns found.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following

```
:%s/^[0-9]  *//
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use instead

```
:%s/^\d\s\+//
```

Being a *text* editor, vim tends to treat more characters literally‒as *text*‒when matching a pattern than perl.  In the default mode, `+` matches literal `+`.

Of course, this is configurable.  Try

```
:%s/\v^\d\s+//
```

and read the help file.

```
:help magic
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the Visual Block mode (Ctrl+V), then move down and to the right to highlight a block of characters and use 'x' to remove them.  Depending on the layout of the line, that may in fact be quicker (and easier to remember).

Answer (score 1):

If you still want to use Perl for this, you can:

```
:%!perl -pe 's/^\d\s+//'
```

Vim will write the file to a temporary file, run the given Perl script on it, and reload the file into the edit buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Escape the plus sign:

```
:%s/^\d\s\+//
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's in a column like that you could go into the column visual mode by pressing:

```
esc ctrl+q
```

then you can highlight what you want to delete